# How to preserve state between tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write an app which:

1. Gets some data from external service API (let it be just a number) every N minutes,
2. Makes actions if received data differ from the previous saved state.

To achieve that, I have a controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

    # to be called every N minutes
    def check
        if @saved_state.nil?
            @saved_state = get_from_API
            return
        end

        @new_state = get_from_API

        if @saved_state != @new_state
            process
            @saved_state = @new_state
        end
    end

    def process
        # some data processing here
    end

    def get_from_API
        # getting data from external API here
    end
end
```

1. How can I save state between check calls? What is the right way to achieve the described goal?
2. Is it OK to use a controller for that, or is there some more appropriate solution, another approach?
3. I plan to use rake task via cron for calling check every N minutes: something like `MyController.new.check`. Is it OK, or is there another way to regularly call some app method on the server?

Comment: If you don't get all the responses you need in this question, consider writing a couple separate questions that can be pinpointed easier

Comment: Have you considered using Redis?